# Using realm from an extension AND pods?

Tags: swift, realm

I am getting a warning from xcode (I'm trying to get realm into an extension and in my project via pods.) the app compiles fine, the extension gives me...

`ld: warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions: /foo/bar/baz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Secretary-gklgwtinpjtwntbnzitbsdzhopid/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
ld: warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions: /foo/bar/baz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Secretary-gklgwtinpjtwntbnzitbsdzhopid/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm.framework/Realm`

is there a way to do this and still use cocoa pods to handle?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

"To configure an app extension target to use an embedded framework, set the target’s “Require Only App-Extension-Safe API” build setting to Yes. If you don’t, Xcode reminds you to do so by displaying the warning “linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions”"

Might help you

Comment: yeah, I had run that down, not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an oversight in the Realm and RealmSwift pod specs. I've pushed a pull request for Realm at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2666 that will address this for future releases.